# Invoking a primitive operation via dot operator fails

Tags: ada

I have a problem understanding how the UFCS (Universal Function Call Syntax) works in Ada.

Let's say I have a type, like:

```
package People
    type Person is tagged private;

    -- This procedure is a primitive operation:
    procedure Say_Name (Person_Object : in Person);
private
    type Person is tagged record
        Name : String;
    end record;
end People;
```

then I can call the procedure as if it actually belonged to the Person type:

```
Some_Person_Instance.Say_Name;
```

Now that works, but in my particular instance it doesn't make sense to have a record, and a subtype would suffice.

```
subtype Person is String;
```

At this point (assuming I changed the procedure's workings), it fails to compile and I get the error:

```
invalid prefix in selected component "Person".
```

Why? It doesn't even help if I do:

```
type Person is new String;
```

Does UFCS only work for records?

I apologize if this is an inane question, but I've no study materials for Ada (apart for couple of e-books) and the textbook I ordered hasn't arrived yet.

Comment: It only works for tagged records (or accesses to tagged records).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UFCS is a [full feature of the D language](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/ufcs.html). For historical reasons, Ada has mixed approaches to calls in different parts of the language.

Ordinary subprogram calls are dealt with in [ARM 6.4](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-6-4.html), and look like `Subprogram_Name (Parameters)` (or just `Subprogram_Name` if there are no parameters).

Protected subprogram calls ([ARM 9.5.1](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-9-5-1.html)) and entry calls ([ARM 9.5.3](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-9-5-3.html)) look like `Object.Subprogram_Or_Entry_Name (Parameters)`.

Primitive subprograms of tagged types, however, can be called either way; either as an ordinary call, or, if the tagged parameter is the first parameter, using the prefix notation ([ARM 4.1.3(9.1)](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-1-3.html#p9.1)).

There is discussion of this design in [AI95-00252](http://www.ada-auth.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/ais/ai-00252.txt?rev=1.16); apparently the designers did consider allowing both call forms for all types, but there were too many complications and too few benefits. A shame, I think we all agree, though perhaps it can be taken too far; the D example (from [here](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/ufcs.html))

```
values.multiply(10).divide(3).evens.writeln;
```

might be a case in point!

---

With regard to learning Ada and Web resources, have a look at the [Ada Resource Association’s resource list](http://www.adaic.org/learn/materials/).

Comment: I've seen it called that in D, so I thought it's a universal thing. I guess it isn't. Thank you very much